# MvcMiniProfiler 1.9 - Step method not being recognized by VS or by the runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I just installed MvcMiniprofiler via NuGet in VS 2010.

I am able to start the profiler and its working smoothly. The problem is that i want to wrap a piece of code in the "Step" method. I followed the example and am using the `using` syntax.

e.g.

```
using(profiler.Step("A"))
{
    // some code to be profiled
}
```

The problem is that neither the asp.net compiler nor visual studio is recognizing what the `Step` method is and at run-time gives me a YSOD saying.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler' does not contain a definition for 'Step' and no extension method 'Step' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler' could be found

Everything else is working fine.

Has the Step method been replaced by something else ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'`.Step` is an extension method - it is designed this way so it has close to 0 performance impact when profiling is off.

You will need this at the top of your file.

`using StackExchange.Profiling;`

Comment: Ha! That was driving me crazy. It's a good design architecturally, but that wasn't very intuitive for the coder.

Comment: @blesh I agree, there are some usability issues there.